# setInterval() não funciona

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Eu estou criando uma aplicação de questões, onde exibe um temporizador, caso o temporizador chegue em 0, a questão será perdida(ou seja, se o usuário não responder a tempo), porém na hora de exibir o numero fica oscilando, ele tenta diminuir porém em seguida volta para "80" ou para "50", fica toda hora entre 79.9 - 80 - 79.9 - 80, não sei porque isso acontece, suspeito que seja algo relacionado quando passo o parâmetro "item.time" para a função, alguém sabe resolver? pff ;-;

a lógica do código é semelhante a este:

```
      let questions = [
        { title: "quanto é 1 + 1?", time: 50 },
        { title: "quanto é 2 + 2?", time: 80 }
    ]
    const [timeQ, setTimeQ] = useState(0)
    let interval;

    function QuestionTimer(tempo) {

        interval = setInterval(()=>{
            setTimeQ(( tempo -= 0.1).toFixed(2))
            console.log(timeQ)

        },100)
        if( tempo <=0){
            errou()
            clearInterval(interval)
        }

    }

    function render() {
        return (
            <div id="timer">
                {questions.map((item, indice) => {
                        if (item.time !== undefined) {

                            return QuestionTimer(item.time)


                        }

                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente declarar a variável tempo também.

```
let interval, tempo;
```

quando chamar a função salve o tempo para ir decrementando

```
function QuestionTimer(tempTempo) {
        tempo = tempTempo;
```

Comment: não funcionou amigo :(, continua oscilando "80-79-80-79"

Comment: É que falta informações para poder analisar o todo. O que faz a função setTimeQ?